# Google App Engine: "[path]" does not refer to a valid SDK directory"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10. Just downloaded the Python SDK for Google App Engine. I type

```
python appcfg.py udaproject319
```

and it says

```
ValueError: GAE_SDK_ROOT '/home/username/app/new_project_template' does not refer to a valid SDK directory
```

I have no idea what this means. What makes a directory an SDK directory? Here are the files I have in the folder:

```
appcfg.py favicon.ico main.py main.pyc
index.yaml udaproject319.yaml
```

Comment: I got it to work by copying all relevant files into the app directory, which is where I had set my path. It works, but I have no idea why that made a difference. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you download and unzip the SDK, you have a folder `google_appengine` somewhere. The sdk directory is something like `/home/username/google_appengine`

when you want deploy or start dev_appserver you type:

```
python [GAE_SDK_ROOT]/appcfg.py update [YOUR_APP_ROOT]
```

for example:

```
python /home/username/google_appengine/appcfg.py update /home/username/udaproject319
```